# Cartalyst Sentry a login is required, none given

Tags: authentication, laravel, cartalyst-sentry, faker

I use Cartalyst Sentry for authentication. When I try to seed my database from command line, I get this error:

```
[Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\LoginRequiredException]  
A login is required for a user, none given.
```

This is my `DatabaseSeeder.php` file:

```php
<?php

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Eloquent::unguard();

        $this->call('PriceChangeOccuredTableSeeder');
    }

}
```

And this is my `PriceChangeOccuredTableSeeder.php` file:

```php
<?php

// Composer: "fzaninotto/faker": "v1.3.0"
use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class PriceChangeOccuredTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run() {
        DB::table('price_change_occured')->delete();

        User::create(array('product_id' => 1, 'owner_id' => 2, 'change_occured' => 1));
    }

}
```

And this is my `PriceChangeOccured` model

```php
<?php

class PriceChangeOccured extends \Eloquent {
    public $table = 'price_change_occured';
}
```

Comment: Your PriceChangeOccuredTableSeeder is using `User::create()`, which will create a User record. Is this what you intended? If so, the error message is due to not providing a user name and password for the new User.

Answer (score 1):

if change your login from "EMAIL" to "USERNAME" ,and every thing was good,you should change these too:

1. in your seed add username too:

   ```
   class UserSeeder extends Seeder
   {
       protected $admin_email = "admin@admin.com";
       protected $admin_password = "password";
       protected $admin_username = "naghipour.me";
   }
   ```
2. find **SentryUserRepository.php** and find **create function** and change to this:

   ```
   $data = array(
             "email"     => $input["email"],
             "password"  => $input["password"],
             "username" => $input["username"]
   );
   ```

Attention: you should add username filed in migration :

```
$table->string('username', 100)->unique();
```

and every where there is email you should add username too.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you are not adding a login to the user. And it seems that you aren't. Thus,  you only need to add the login (or email) depending on how your User table works.

I'm assuming that a email/login and password woud be required for your user table. And you are not providing any of those when you create the user on this example.